# How to use has_many through with namespace models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, namespaces, associations

I have a name spaced model called `Accounting::Invoice`

I also have a model called `Contact`

An `Accounting::Invoice` has many contacts through another model called `Contactable` -- this is in cases where an invoice is split across more than one contact.

But for some reason, I can't get the `has_many through` association to work.

I can get it to work in one direction, ex: `Contact.first.accounting_invoices`, but going the other way, ex: `Accounting::Invoices.first.contacts` gives me an error that looks like:

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: contactables.invoice_id...`

Any ideas? I'm not sure where ActiveRecord is getting `contactabes.invoice_id`. I've defined my table names and class names explicitly to use the `accounting_invoices` table and `Accounting::Invoice` class respectfully.

Comment: Please show how you set up the associations in both models, and any other possibly relevant model setup (like a custom `table_name`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:foreign_key => 'accounting_invoice_id` option to tell rails which field to use. Check out the docs of `has_many` for more informations (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

The relevant part is:

```
:foreign_key
Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of this class in lower-case and “_id” suffixed. So a Person class that makes a has_many association will use “person_id” as the default :foreign_key.
```